# How do I configure ANY web server to accept POST requests that have No Host and absolute request URIS?

Tags: web-services, webserver, jetty

I have a client that sends http requests with absolute request uris and does not define "host"

There for a web server like Jetty rejects the POST request saying:

> org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 400: No Host

Is there any way to configure jetty or any other web server to accept post requests that don't have a host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.4

A client MUST send a Host header for it to be compliant to HTTP/1.1

If you send an absolute URI in the target, then the `Host` header must be the same as what is found in that absolute URI target.

Note that the HTTP/1.1 spec even states ...

> A server MUST respond with a 400 (Bad Request) status code to any
> HTTP/1.1 request message that lacks a Host header field and to any
> request message that contains more than one Host header field or a
> Host header field with an invalid field-value.

This makes it a requirement to respond with error 400 in this situation, always.

If you use HTTP/2, then you can avoid this because the split between target URI and Host header was addressed with the `:authority` pseudo-header.

See https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7540.html#rfc.section.8.1.2.3

Comment: is there any way to circumvent this requirement in Jetty or some other web server? say to still accept requests that have no host?

Comment: that would be a fundamental spec violation.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot change the client code which is sending these invalid requests.

Comment: Is there a version of jetty or other webserver that run HTTP/2?

Comment: Jetty 9.3+ supports HTTP/2

Comment: if you have a bad client, its likely that this client isn't supporting HTTP/2 yet.

Comment: The client is trying to send am http 1.1 request I think. I need to just disable the error somehow on the server

Comment: Even if you could configure that on the server, any intermediary (proxy, gateway, router, firewall, load balancer, etc) that follows the spec can also fail the request with error 400 before it even reaches your server.

Comment: Joakim, would the approach you suggest here work for me? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40687837

Add an intercepter to Jetty

Comment: You would essentially be recreating the entire SSL and HTTP layers, a non-trivial amount of work you are about to enter into.

Comment: Maybe it's easier to comment out a few lines of code and then recompile jetty

Comment: then you'll have to fix all of the security issues and null pointers you just created.  make sure you address it on the correct RFC level (Jetty supports both RFC2616 and RFC7230).

Comment: And ensure you handle the HTTP version behaviors properly too (0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 2), you don't want to be changing the behaviors for other versions of HTTP when you make this change.

Comment: you might have better luck looking into haproxy or nginx and see if they can rewrite the request Host header (before rejecting it themselves) and then forward the request to Jetty.  Consider even just changing the request from HTTP/1.1 (which requires the Host header) to HTTP/1.0 (which doesn't have this requirement)

Comment: Can these tools change the request type from 1.1 to 1.0?